# Unable to understand python 3.12 relative imports

Tags: python, relative-import

I have a directory structure as shown below:

```
postApp
    Routers
        Post.py
        User.py
        __init__.py
    Database.py
    Main.py
    Models.py
    Schemas.py
    Utils.py
    __init__.py
```

In the main.py file, I have tried to relative imports of database, models, schemas and utils modules. Unfortunately, it always gives error like "unable to do relative import from an unknown package name"

Normal imports do work, so I didn't pay much attention to relative imports just yet, until I defined routers folder and had to perform relative import of database and other modules in post and user. It failed with error - "cannot perform relative import beyond top level package"

these files are a present in a directory called "postApp". I put below statement in all the py files, except

```
    __init__
```

(they are empty).

```
    print(__package__ +'.'+__name__)
```

Then I went outside the postApp folder and run a test.py script with following statements:

```
    from postApp import main, database, utils, schemas
    from postApp.routers import post, user

    print(__name__)
```

The output in anything I would have expected to be:

```
    postApp.postApp.database
```

```
    postApp.postApp.models
```

```
    postApp.postApp.main
```

```
    postApp.postApp.utils
```

```
    postApp.postApp.schemas
```

```
    postApp.routers.postApp.routers.post
```

```
    postApp.routers.postApp.routers.user
```

```
    __main__
```

I have no idea why parent package names are repeated twice. Look at the 2nd and 3rd last outputs, conceptually it should've been "postApp.routers.post" and "postApp.routers.user".

please help!

tried to do relative import but it doesn't work

Comment: It did, partially. Later on I looked at PEP 366 and the Language Reference: Import System. Finally understood how the import system works in python (at least for my use case). Relative imports are not subject to relative paths but instead, connected to three attributes, namely, __spec__, __package__ and __name__. Though __spec__ gives complete detail about a file/module and __name__ is the fully qualified name of the module, it is primarily __package__ that is referenced when we use single . operator in import statements. Double dot means parent of current package.

Comment: However, there is one big exception to this. When a file is run as __main__, it's __package__ attribute is set to None, hence the dot operator will never work for a __main__ file. To fix my problem, I shifted my main.py file to outside of App folder and it worked.